# Using pasted string or file upload

Tags: javascript, forms, file, web

I have a web form where a user is uploading between one and two files. Each file can be given through a file input or by pasting text into a text box.

How can I standardize the input so that it is sent to the server in the same fashion regardless of the method used to input? I want to send the server one type of data always, either a multipart request with a file or a JSON request with the file as a string. How?

Right now, I'm trying to read files using a FileReader, but I am confused about handling asynchronous reads.

```
function getPrimaryFileString() {
    if(pasted()) {
        return document.getElementById("pastedPrimaryInputFile").value;
    } else {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var file = document.getElementById("primaryInputFile").files[0];
        reader.readAsText(file);

        filestring = reader.contents;

        return filestring;
    }
}
```

I know that I am supposed to have an `onload` callback, but I don't know how I would do that and be able to return the filestring like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for anyone else struggling with this, I found a solution. I added an onchange method for each of the file inputs, like below.

```
 <input type="file" 
        id="primaryInputFile" 
        name="primaryInputFile" 
        size="10"
        onchange="mainFileChanged()" />
```

The function just told a globally-declared `FileReader` to read the updated value.

```
function mainFileChanged() {
    console.log("Main file change recorded");
    mainFileInput.readAsText(document.getElementById('primaryInputFile').files[0]);
}
```

I then just returned the reader's contents when needed. It's not a perfect solution, but it works.